# Leer una Url linea por linea con java

Tags: java

Hola estoy trabajando en una aplicacion web con java pero tengo problemas para leer una url linea por linea y luego almacenar lo leido en una lista, me aparece el error Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL... en la linea BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); lo extraño es que cuando lo ejecuto en una clase local y muestro por consola el texto de la url no me marca error.
Aquí esta el código:

```
String archivo = "https://miurl"
String str1="";
            try{
                URL url = new URL(archivo);
                System.out.println("--url  "+url);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                System.out.println("----------- "+in);
                while((str1=in.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println("str1 "+ str1);
                    claves.add(str1);
                }

                in.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return claves;
```

Les agradezco mucho su ayuda :D

Comment: El mensaje `Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL` indica un problema con la URL en sí, parece que necesitas autorización para acceder a ese recurso. No creo que te funcione sin más en otro contexto a no ser que donde funciona uses una URL distinta o te autentifiques de algún modo.

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano. Se que 403 indica que la url esta prohibida, pero ya revise el fichero al quiero entrar y no esta como privado, además si copio la url directo en un navegador si me permite ver el contenido. Y como explicaba al principio cuando ejecuto el codigo en una aplicación local si me muestra el contenido de la url por consola, aqui dejo el código que uso ejecutando desde local

Comment: Ya, pero el servidor puede estar bloqueando la petición, porque entiende que no viene de un browser. Quizá trabajando los encabezados de la petición o algo así podrías acceder al recurso, no sé.

Comment: Ok, voy a checar esto que me comentas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano, pueba indicando este encabezado ""User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me puse a investigar lo de los headers, ya me funciono.
Saludos.